# PDO + input term + mysql

Tags: php, search, pdo

I'm using PDO bindValue to search terms through my database. Is my syntax all wrong? I'm not getting the result I'm supposed to

```
$term = $_GET['s'];
$s_pdo = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = ':search'");
$s_pdo -> bindValue(':search',"%".$term."%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
$s_pdo -> execute();

while($s_row = $s_pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $s_row['value'];
}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong here? I do have the value in my mysql. I'm matching exactly in mysql to test if my search function works.

Thanks!

Comment: Try running the query from phpmyadmin and see if it returns any rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to remove the % from the bindValue part..:

```
$s_pdo = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = :search");
$s_pdo -> bindValue(':search',$term,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

or use LIKE so you can leave the %:

```
$s_pdo = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value LIKE :search");
$s_pdo -> bindValue(':search',"%".$term."%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to quote prepared placeholders. Also, when using `%term%`, you should be using `LIKE` instead of `=` The prepare action does it for you!

```
$term = $_GET['s'];
$s_pdo = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value LIKE :search");
$s_pdo -> bindValue(':search',"%".$term."%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
$s_pdo -> execute();

while($s_row = $s_pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $s_row['value'];
}
```

Also, next time, for better error debugging, enable `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` using `PDO::setAttribute()` method.

Comment: i took those quotes out and it still doesn't give me what I'm looking for. Can you do an example with errmode_exception and setAttribute() amd I supposed to put those in the fetchAll()?

Comment: `$s_pdo->setAttribute("PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE", "PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION");` right after creating the new PDO object